# Creating custom redistributable Eclipse - issue with launcher.library

Tags: eclipse

I am creating a custom version of Eclipse Neon, installing certain plugins, tweaking settings, etc. My plan is to redistribute this to everyone on my team. However I am just discovering that the plugins are being saved in a local user ~/.p2 directory that the Eclipse installer must have created or something. I would like a fully self contained Eclipse with no reference to user specific directories. I notice that in the eclipse.INI file there is indeed a reference to this local directory.

```
--launcher.library
C:\Users\zeroalpha\.p2\pool\plugins\org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_64_1.1.400.v20160518-1444
```

When I delete it and try to launch Eclipse I get this error

[image]

How can I make a redistribute eclipse that doesn't rely on the local user ~/.p2 directory?

update: This is the error I get when launching after telling eclipse.INI to point to the launcher jar in the eclipse plugins directory instead of the local ~./p2
[image]

Comment: If  you are using the Oomph installer that is where it installs things.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, I used the Oomph installer to install Neon originally. I then modified my installed version, zipped it up, and would like to redistribute. I Just tried to tell my eclipse.INI  to point to the launcher JAR in the eclipse/plugins directory and I received a different type of error. I will update my question with it.

Comment: It sounds like you actually want to create a new RCP based on normal Eclipse plus your plugins. So you will have to go through the RCP building procedure. If you want to use the Oomph installer [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Oomph/article.html) looks like it might be what you need.

Comment: @greg-449 seems like overkill to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying and "zipping up" an Eclipse installation is not the right approach for what you're trying to do. Instead, look at the capabilities of the [Oomph project](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.oomph) (the project behind Eclipse's own standard installer). Specifically, read up about [Oomph Authoring](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse_Oomph_Authoring) to learn how to create your own installer package that includes exactly the plug-ins and configuration you want.

As @greg-449 pointed out in the coments, [Lars Vogel's tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Oomph/article.html) is also useful.

Comment: I've seen this done before though and it worked fine. I've used a zipped up eclipse distribution very similar to the one I'm making and I had no problems with it. Its launcher library and plugins were all located in its own plugin directory, but I can't figure out how to make that happen. Trying to learn all about this Oomph seems like a giant headache for something I know can be done without it.

Comment: Also, can you explain why it is not the right approach?

Comment: Well, as you're seeing Eclipse doesn't really want to go that way any more. In the past, it was somewhat feasible although maintaining such a "distribution" is a big PITA. Now with the installer and how it takes advantage of shared bundle pools, it's just not as feasible. Can you make it work with enough effort? Probably. Is it fighting against Eclipse's intended use? Definitely.